# How to change anchor pane background in AvalonDock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I have a simple .xaml file for my GUI:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xced="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xced:DockingManager Background="Gray">
            <xced:LayoutRoot>
                <xced:LayoutPanel>
                    <xced:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <xced:LayoutAnchorable>

                        </xced:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xced:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </xced:LayoutPanel>
            </xced:LayoutRoot>
        </xced:DockingManager>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

All I want to do is to change the background, and I can achieve this via the Background attribute, but it is not consistent with the anchor pane as shown in the picture:

[image]

How can I also change that white to gray?

Comment: Please show us how you changed the `Background`.

Comment: @jstreet with this line: <xced:DockingManager Background="Gray">

Comment: @jstreet the solution is to load a theme, those elements are buttons that have on top of them pictures, so they are not affected the background attribute. Now my question is how to customize a theme. There are some NugetPackages that I can build on top I think such as MetroTheme.

Comment: Their sample code has a theme example.

Answer (score 0):

Theming is the way to solve this - you can either find a themed version (there are a few to be found on the Internet) or you edit/override items in the [Generic.xaml](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/blob/master/source/Components/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Themes/generic.xaml) file of the AvalonDock DLL.

For example at about Line 400 part of the AnchorablePineTitle:

```
              <Button x:Name="PART_HidePin"
                      Grid.Column="3"
                      Focusable="False"
                      Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      Command="{Binding Path=LayoutItem.HideCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      ToolTip="{x:Static avalonDockProperties:Resources.Anchorable_BtnClose_Hint}">
                <Border Background="White">
                  <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/PinClose.png">
                  </Image>
                </Border>
</Button>
```